# Horizontal enumitem, with images?

Tags: graphics, enumitem, inline

I'd like to make a horizontal list with 4 items, each being a picture of square side and roughly 0.4\linewidth wide. I tried to use inline enumitem, but the image keep going to next rows instead of the same row. I have code looking like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumitem*}
        \item \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{img1}
        \item \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{img2}
        \item \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{img3}
        \item \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{img4}
    \end{enumitem*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What does 4 x 0.4`\linewidth` give you (plus the enumerations)? Does that exceed the current `\linewidth`?

Comment: I think you'd better use a package like`subcaption` (`subfigure` environment) or `floatrow` (`subfloatrow` environment). Or even the `tasks` environment: the figures would be aligned in columns.

Comment: I hope your real code is better. The name of the environment is `enumerate*` not `enumitem*`. Also you are not loading graphicx.

Comment: I'd like the images to float automatically, so 4 0.4\textwidth would order the images in 2 rows of 2 each.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you really want to achieve, a numbered list of figures, four subfigures with captions, or just four horizontal images. But, the sum of widths exceeds a whole `\textwidth`, so you need to reduce it and there is no environment named `enumitem*`, choose `enumerate` or `itemize*` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize*}[label={}]
        \item \includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth]{img1}
        \item \includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth]{img2}
        \item \includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth]{img3}
        \item \includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth]{img4}
    \end{itemize*}
\end{document}
```